# How to substitute the below string using gvim %s command

Tags: vim, substitution

I want to substitute this

```
disable iff (!(gth_ibuf_p[i].pwr_good_rst_b && gth_ibuf_p[i].reset_b)
```

by

```
disable iff (((gth_ibuf_p[i].pwr_good_rst_b || gth_ibuf_p[i].reset_b) !== 1)
```

The command, I used is

```
:%s/disable iff (!(gth_ibuf_p[i\].pwr_good_rst_b && gth_ibuf_p[i\].reset_b)/disable iff (((gth_ibuf_p[i\].pwr_good_rst_b || gth_ibuf_p[i\].reset_b) !== 1)/gc
```

and it shows

```
the pattern is not found
```

I searched for these patterns individually it was hitting. in %s its not happening.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: :%s/disable iff (!(gth_ibuf_p[i\].pwr_good_rst_b && gth_ibuf_p[i\].reset_b)/disable iff (((gth_ibuf_p[i\].pwr_good_rst_b || gth_ibuf_p[i\].reset_b) !== 1)/gc

Comment: Oh my gosh, please learn how to properly format your question; same for comments. Simple code highlighting by indenting 4 spaces or enclosing in backticks.

Answer (score 3):

Just :

```
:%s/\V..your.pattern..../..your..replacement../gc
```

add the `\V` after `:s/` to use `very nomagic`. Do a `:h magic` to see details.

Comment: In the general case, you also need to put a `\` in front of every `\` and `/` (the `:substitute` separator; you can use a different character, too). The pattern / replacement in your question doesn't have any of those, though.